# Get @-identifier of Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, identifier

I have an JavaScript object looking like this:

```
Object {@attributes: Object,…}
```

So how can I access the @attributes-Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent["@attributes"]`, thus:

```
var parent = { "@attributes" : someObj} ;
console.log(parent["@attributes"]);
```

In JS, all property names can be used as named array elements. Most (i.e. those without spaces etc) can be used as bare property names.

```
var foo = { bar: 1};

foo.bar = 2 // or
foo["bar"] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var myObject = { '@attributes': 'foo' };
var result = myObject['@attributes']; // foo
```